# How to calculate different percentage of weight and round up or down depending on value

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an app in JS that outputs the weight I should be lifting in the gym based on a weight I provide in an input element. The 'calculator' app for this will have predetermined values based on specific workout programs stored in  objects within an array. These will be called based on what workout is selected from the dropdown box.

One workout program for example utilizes unduluating periodization and so week one would be 65, 75 and 85% calculated from a training max. I understand I just need to do (weight / 100) * percentage to get the result. However, this doesn't factor in values that are not rounded/whole numbers, such as 102.5 or 112 for example, 117.5, 22.5 etc.

How could I implement this into my app?

**EXAMPLE:**
65% of 125(kg) is 81.25(kg)

**PROBLEM:**
81.25(kg) is not a weight you can put on the bar in most gyms, the closest weight would be either 80kg or 82.5kg

**SOLUTION:** Depending on choice, increase to 82.5(kg) or lower to 80(kg)

```js
const workouts = [
  {
type: "531",
supp: "bbs",
amrap: true,
sets: {
  main: {
    percentages: {
      week1_1: 65,
      week1_2: 75,
      week1_3: 85,
      week2_1: 70,
      week2_2: 80,
      week2_3: 90,
      week3_1: 75,
      week3_2: 85,
      week3_3: 95,
    },
  },
  supp: {
    reps: 5,
    set1: 65,
    set2: 65,
    set3: 65,
    set4: 65,
    set5: 65,
  },
},
  },
];


function calculateNow(opt) // opt is this and this is input element with an oninput event listener {
  const allRadios = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-radio");
  const allText = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-result");
  const optParent = opt.classList[1];
  const inputWeight = opt.value;
  allRadios.forEach(function(radio) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      switch (optParent) {
        case "di-1":
          if (radio.classList.contains("r-1")) {
            const calcWk1S1 =
              (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_1 // 65;
            const number = calcWk1S1 % 1;
            console.log(calcWk1S1);
            if (number < 0.5) {
              allText[0].textContent = Math.floor(calcWk1S1);
            } else {
              allText[0].textContent = Math.ceil(calcWk1S1);
            }
            const calcWk1S2 =
              (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_2 // 75;
            allText[1].textContent = calcWk1S2;
            const calcWk1S3 =
              (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_3 // 85;
            allText[2].textContent = calcWk1S3;
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some kind of detail of some expected inputs and their equivalent outputs, along with what you have now that is incorrect? I wasn't quite able to tell from the question

Comment: Can you update to provide what `opt` is also along with the expected results previously asked for

Comment: FWIW I would suggest `calcWk1S1` be changed to avoid confusion with `calcWklSl` or `calcWk151`etc.

Comment: You should always lift a multiple of 750Lbs :) be superman

Comment: `workouts` is not defined here

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer**

If you want to ensure all weight outputs are integers, you can just apply the [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) function before printing to the screen.

Also the `const number = calcWk1S1 % 1;` will always return 0 since all numbers mod 1 are equivalent to 0, so you need to remove that ;)

**Updated code**

Your final formula may look something like this:

```
const calcWk1S1 =
  (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_1;
allText[0].textContent = Math.round(calcWk1S1);
const calcWk1S2 =
  (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_2;
allText[1].textContent = Math.round(calcWk1S2);
const calcWk1S3 =
  (inputWeight / 100) * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1_3;
allText[2].textContent = Math.round(calcWk1S3);
```

**Optional optimization for readability and scalability**

Or reduce the copy-paste by changing the hard-coded constants from:

```
workouts = [
  {
    sets: {
      main: {
        percentages: {
          week1_1: number,
          week1_2: number,
          week1_3: number
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
```

...to an array like this:

```
workouts = [
  {
    sets: {
      main: {
        percentages: {
          week1: [ number, number, number ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
```

And then you can reduce your code down to this:

```
allText.forEach((element, index) => {
  const weight = inputWeight * workouts[0].sets.main.percentages.week1[index] / 100;
  element.textContent = Math.round(weight);
});
```